# How to use waitForMessage properly?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

I am trying to use the function ros:topic::waitForMessage in order to get one time a nav_msgs::Path message.
As waitForMessage is overloaded, I am using the following definition :

```
boost::shared_ptr<M const> ros::topic::waitForMessage (const std::string &topic, ros::NodeHandle &nh )
```

Here is the extract of my main where is located the function :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "create_path");
  ros::NodeHandle create_path;
  nav_msgs::Path path = ros::topic::waitForMessage("/path_planned/edge", create_path);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
  while (ros::ok()){
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I don't get how to use properly this function. When I catkin_make this code, I get these errors :

```
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp:63:86: error: no matching function for call to ‘waitForMessage(const char [19], ros::NodeHandle&)’
   nav_msgs::Path &path = ros::topic::waitForMessage("/path_planned/edge", create_path);
                                                                                      ^
In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:55:0,
                 from /home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/topic.h:135:28: note: candidate: template<class M> boost::shared_ptr<const M> ros::topic::waitForMessage(const string&, ros::NodeHandle&)
 boost::shared_ptr<M const> waitForMessage(const std::string& topic, ros::NodeHandle& nh)
                            ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/topic.h:135:28: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp:63:86: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘M’
   nav_msgs::Path &path = ros::topic::waitForMessage("/path_planned/edge", create_path);
                                                                                      ^
coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/src/create_path.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/src/create_path.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1371: recipe for target 'coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

After this error, I changed the line of waitForMessage in my program. There is the new line :

```
nav_msgs::Path path = ros::topic::waitForMessage<nav_msgs::Path>("/path_planned/edge", create_path);
```

I tried to catkin_make again and I got this new error :

```
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/stagiaire019/astek_ws/src/coverage_path_planning/src/create_path.cpp:63:67: error: conversion from ‘boost::shared_ptr<const nav_msgs::Path_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to non-scalar type ‘nav_msgs::Path {aka nav_msgs::Path_<std::allocator<void> >}’ requested
   nav_msgs::Path path = ros::topic::waitForMessage<nav_msgs::Path>("/path_planned/edge", create_path);
                                                                   ^
coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/src/create_path.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/src/create_path.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1371: recipe for target 'coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [coverage_path_planning/CMakeFiles/create_path.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I don't understand how this works, so if anyone know how to use properly waitForMessage, I will be pleased.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293890/how-to-use-waitformessage-properly-?/) by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2018-06-12

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to understand shared pointers.
[Here](https://answers.ros.org/question/73258/detecting-timeout-from-waitformessage/) is another question that shows a similar solution.

---

Originally posted by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) with karma: 811 on 2018-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on 2018-06-13**:
It worked ! Thank you !

I've edited my question to show the solution at the end.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-13**:
@antonin_haulot can you please create an *answer* containing your solution rather than putting it in your *question*?

**Comment by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) on 2018-06-19**:
@jayess done !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my solution :

```
  boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Path const> sharedEdge;
  nav_msgs::Path edge;
  sharedEdge = ros::topic::waitForMessage<nav_msgs::Path>("/path_planned/edge",create_path);
  if(sharedEdge != NULL){
    edge = *sharedEdge;
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [antonin_haulot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34400/antonin_haulot/) with karma: 215 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NagaDinesh1194](https://answers.ros.org/users/40046/nagadinesh1194/) on 2019-03-06**:
This worked for me perfectly! Thank you

**Comment by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on 2019-06-25**:
All ROS messages define typedefs to make it easier to use the shared pointer version. For example,
instead of `boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Path>`, you can write `nav_msgs::PathPtr` or `nav_msgs::Path::Ptr`. Likewise, instead of `boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Path const>`, you can write `nav_msgs::PathConstPtr` or `nav_msgs::Path::ConstPtr`.